# Непонятный результат позиционирования курсора по вертикали

Tags: delphi

Доброе время суток.
У меня есть программа, в которой я решил, по нажатию на кнопку, проверять находится ли курсор мышки над этой кнопкой. Следующим методом:

```
    procedure TFMain.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  P, P1, L_PosCursor: TPoint;
begin
  P := ClientToScreen(Point(Button3.Left, Button3.Top));
  P1 := ClientToScreen(Point(Button3.Left + Button3.Width, Button3.Top + Button3.Height));
  GetCursorPos(L_PosCursor);

 if PtInRect(Rect(P.X, P.Y, P1.X, P1.Y), (Point(L_PosCursor.X, L_PosCursor.Y))) then   

    showmessage('курсор находится над кнопкой'+#13#10+'Координаты кнопки: '+Inttostr(P.x)+', '+Inttostr(P.y)+', '+Inttostr(P1.x)+', '+Inttostr(P1.y)
                                                 +#13#10+Inttostr((L_PosCursor.X))+', '+Inttostr((L_PosCursor.Y)))
  else showmessage('курсор НЕ находится над кнопкой'+#13#10+'Координаты кнопки: '+Inttostr(P.x)+', '+Inttostr(P.y)+', '+Inttostr(P1.x)+', '+Inttostr(P1.y)
                                                       +#13#10+Inttostr((L_PosCursor.X))+', '+Inttostr((L_PosCursor.y))); 
end;
```

Но программа в ответ на это выдала результат (рис 3).
На что я взял и запихнул этот код в пустое приложение (рис 2), оказалось он корректно РАБОТАЕТ.

Тогда я взял и упростил мою программу до «нельза» (рис 1)
Выяснилось несоответствие, (рис.1 и рис2 сравнение «*.dfm»), которое не давало правильно работать.
Вопрос:
Почему, кнопка в контейнере «TPageControl», дает не правильные координаты курсора, в отличие от кнопки, которая непосредственно находилась на форме? Все высчитывается относительно экрана, а не формы, и там отличие только в высоте курсора, по горизонтале он входит в ширину кнопки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш подход к локализации ошибки достоин похвалы, так держать :)

Теперь по делу. Уважаемый *KoVadim* все правильно говорит, только для перевода координат правильнее будет вызывать этот метод у самой кнопки (ей виднее на ком она там лежит):

```
P := Button3.ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0));
P1 := Button3.ClientToScreen(Point(Button3.Width, Button3.Height));
```

В таком случае вам не нужно помнить\знать где лежит кнопка (на форме, панели или в другом контейнере).

Answer (score 1):

Функция ClientToScreen, которую Вы вызываете, переводит координаты дочерних объектов... На самом деле, ClientToScreen - это метод. И в данном случае, это метод формы. И переводит он координаты компонентов относительно себя.

Когда кнопка находится на форме - все ок, когда же она на PageControl, то координаты кнопки считаются от PageControl, а переводите вы их в экранные как будто кнопка на форме (да, она как бы на форме, но через прослойку).

Если я правильно все помню, то будет достаточно просто так

```
P := pcMain.ClientToScreen(Point(Button3.Left, Button3.Top));
```